# How to change which class variable is being called depending on user input?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, class-variables

I've created a class called `Earthquake` which stores relevant earthquake data (its magnitude, time it hit, etc.) in class variables. I want to ask the user which data they'd like to see, then print out that data for them like so:

```
earthquake1 = Earthquake()

answer = input("What data would you like to see?")
print(earthquake1.answer)
```

In the example above, if the user answers `magnitude`, I want to print out the class variable `earthquake1.magnitude`.

Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: if statements? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Probably `getattr`... also easily done with `eval` but `eval` is evil

Comment: @dfasoro I'd rather not use if statements because I've got over 20 attributes

Comment: Ok, @A.J. 's answer below should suffice, I will suggest you sanitize/filter the input in case you have some attributes (asides the 20) in the earthquake object you don't necessarily want the user to see.

Comment: How do `Earthquake` instances know about what earthquake they're about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`getattr`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm):

```
earthquake1 = Earthquake()

answer = input("What data would you like to see?")
print(getattr(earthquake1, answer))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `getattr` which is equivalent to `earthquake.attr_name`. The difference is that `getattr` allows you to use a variable to access the name and supply a default value if that is not found.

In short:

```
 print(getattr(earthquake1, answer))
```

Or, if you need to use a default value instead of raising a `KeyError`:

```
print(getattr(earthquake1, answer, "Instance variable {} not found".format(answer)))
```